# Debug Diagnostic not generating dumps on Crash

Tags: debugging, iis-6, windbg, sos, mscorwks.dll

I have configured DebugDiag to monitor all app pools for crashes. One of our App pool stopped today but DD did not generate any dump files. Event Viewer shows the error:

**Application Poole  is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the processes serving that application Pool.**

Currently there are no breakpoints added to DD and first chance exception is not enabled.

Are they really required to get the dump generated? Any special IIS Config required?

I'm on win 2003 with Debug Diag 1.2.

It has generated dumps in the past for memory but haven't seen any crash dumps so far.

Your help will be greatly appreciated, pleaseee guide.